# Reinstalling a Package Again and Again

Tags: packages, compiling

I am using WinEdt on my computer for quite a while. I have recently started using WinEdt on my laptop, and here I have a problem - every time I compile my code (CTRL+SHIFT+P) I am required by latex to reinstall a certain package -

> The required file
>
> tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
>
> is missing...

Then it gives me an option to install it manually, but afterwards I try to compile again, and get the same message!

Comment: Open the MikTeX Package Manager and install the package with adm privileges. Then refresh the database.

Comment: Either the installation failed, then you should try to do it directly with the package manager, or the package databases from miktex are out of sync. In this case open the package managers (user and and admin) and use repositories - synchronize.